# How to remove marker added map with .addTo() function in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, cartography, layers, markers

I am having trouble removing marker which is added with marker.addTo(map). The remove works correctly if added as layer `map.addLayer(marker)` and then `map.removeLayer(marker)`. But `removelayer` is not working with `.addTo()`.

Comment: Strange? `marker.addTo(map)` is normally just a shortcut for `map.addLayer(marker)`. So `map.removeLayer(marker)` should work for both cases...

Comment: I am using easyButton plugin for leaflet and map.addLayer() is not working with it. So I used addTo() and map.removeLayer() is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Leaflet.EasyButton](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton) is a plugin that creates a **control** (button), not a marker (which is a type of layer). That is why the `map.addLayer` (and `map.removeLayer`) is not working with it.

You should use the [`map.addControl`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-addcontrol) and [`map.removeControl`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-removecontrol) methods instead.

The `.addTo` shortcut works in all cases because the object (marker or control) knows which map method it has to re-direct to.

Comment: Yes, now I have a clear idea. Thank you for your information and for you help. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var marker=L.marker(....).addTo(map);
    marker.remove();
```